# Terminal Server - Task Manager disapears Windows 2003 Server

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2003, terminal-services

A bit of a problem on our Server 2003 Windows, from time to time terminal server manager stops working and I couldn't see any active sessions, so I went over to task manager to see the processes/sessions of my RDP users but task manager just goes straight to system tray and won't maximize...This happens like once or twice a week and the only way to resolve it is to reboot the machine.

All the patches and updates has been applied.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: My thoughts. A number of Viruses have this behavior. Wouldn't be a bad idea to do a scan. Also, if you right click it in the notification area try turning off Always on Top (this probably won't do anything, but hey, it's an option). When you right click Task Manager on it's minimized state on the taskbar is the move option available? If so, maybe it is on a phantom monitor, use arrow keys to move back. I'm guessing you have tried the Restore option and the Maximize option from the right click menu? Have you tried start > run > taskmgr when task manager is minimized?